# WS2811 LED Strip Driver

Tags: mosfet, led-strip, mosfet-driver, led-driver, ws2811

I'm in the process of designing a LED strip driver using a WS2811 chip and 3 MOSFETs.  I've attached the schematic below.  I based it on the reference circuit in the WS2811 datasheet ([link](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2811.pdf)), and [this breakout board](https://www.freetronics.com.au/products/addressable-triple-n-mosfet-driver-output-module#.XHNe8uJKg8Y) from Freetronics ([link to schematic](https://www.robotshop.com/media/files/pdf/FREENFET3-v1_0-schematic.pdf)).  I think I'm on the right track with my design, but I had a few questions before I go ahead and order parts.

1. I have selected the BSS138 MOSFET to drive the NTD4806NG MOSFET which will drive the LEDs.  Is the BSS138 actually needed for the MOSFETs I have selected?  I read over the datasheet for the NTD4806 and it looks like it might be ok at a 5v logic level, but a lot of the WS2811 MOSFET drivers I've seen included the smaller MOSFETs.
2. Are N-Channel MOSFETs the right choice to go with the WS2811?  Or should I be using a P-Channel MOSFETs circuit. I've seen a few other people build similar circuits both ways - why might I favour one over the other?
3. Can anyone spot any other "gotchas" with my design that I might be missing?

Thanks for all the help!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. It is not good to have such high value (10K) pull-up resistors on the MOSFET gates. It will result in a poor (slow) rise time and have the MOSFET in a linear region for some microseconds. It translates to extra heat. Try to keep them under 1K if possible, and as low as 150 ohms if possible. That would give you a fast rise (ON) time for the LEDs. It will avoid 'bleeding colors' as well.

Comment: Reviving this year old thread... So did you end up building your board as planned ? Also, why did you change the NTD5867NLT4G to a NTD4806NG MOSFET to drive the LEDs ? Regards